# How to optionally start docker-compose dependent container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose project which (simplified) looks like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  main:
    image: main-image
    depends_on:
      - my_service
  my_service:
    image: very-big-image
```

The functionality supplied by my-service is also available in the cloud. Running it locally is faster, but demands extreme CPU and disk resources. Therefore, I will sometimes want to run just main, and other times will want to run both containers.

I don't want to duplicate the docker-compose code; the full container definitions are much more complex than the simplified version above.

I thought I could put each service in its own `.yml` file and then do `docker-compose -f main.yml -f my_service.yml up`, but that fails on the `depends-on` line, which seems to require the dependency to be in the same file.

For now, I have an ugly solution.  I split into two (with the second files starting with the `depends_on` line. I then use a shell script that knows which configuration I want to run, and either runs the first file or concatenates the two files together.  This works, I guess; but is ugly.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: using `docker-compose start SERVICE_NAME` will start one or the other service, The issue that you will have though is that in your mock `yml` you have a `depends on` which means that _even if_ you `docker-compose start main`, it will still start `my_service` but you can however `docker-compose start my_service` which will start alone. 

If you are worried that your app is too resource hungry, why not tweak docker to not use as much CPU, that way your PC won't work too hard but your app will just take a little longer to start :)

Comment: The problem is not the CPU that docker uses; it is the disk space used by my_service. It is a huge service and does not fit on some computers. Therefore, the app has the option of running it either locally (via the docker service) or by remote calls to a remote copy of the service in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
docker-compose start <container_name>
```

This command only starts a selected container.

Comment: not sure why this is downvoted as this is an elegent solution

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you, and agree that they should have given a reason.
But, this doesn't actually solve my problem, which is caused by needing a dependency on a container that may not always exist.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the right way to do this?

I think you've already identified it: split the service definitions between two files, so that sometimes you can start both:

```
docker-compose -f main.yml -f service.yml up
```

And sometimes you can start just the service container:

```
docker-compose -f service.yml up
```

This works fine, and the `depends_on` key does not require that all definitions be in the same file.  The dictionaries are merged before docker-compose tries to resolve dependencies.

For example, if I have in `main.yml`:

```
---
version: "3"
services:
  main:
    image: alpine
    command: sleep 30
    depends_on:
      - service
```

And in `service.yml`:

```
---
version: "3"
services:
  service:
    image: alpine
    command: sleep 30
```

I can start just the `service` container like this:

```
$ docker-compose -f service.yml up
Starting compose_service_1 ... done
Attaching to compose_service_1
```

Or I can start both the `main` and `service` containers:

```
$ docker-compose -f main.yml -f service.yml up
Starting compose_service_1 ... done
Starting compose_main_1    ... done
Attaching to compose_service_1, compose_main_1
```

If you're seeing behavior that appears to contradict this, it would help if you were to update your question with minimal examples that reproduce the problem, and include any error output from running `docker-compose`.

Comment: This is way over complicated for OPs question

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm not at my desk now but will try to reproduce tomorrow.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that you misunderstood my question.
I need to sometimes run main without service; not service without main.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this would (now, Q3 2023) work:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  main:
    image: main-image
    depends_on:
      my_service:
        condition: "service_started"
        required: false
  my_service:
    image: very-big-image
```

See "**[Optional depends_on with Docker Compose v2.20.2+](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/optional-depends-on-with-docker-compose-v2-20-2)**" from [Nick Janetakis](https://nickjanetakis.com/about).

His explanation:

> ### How Does It Work?
>
> Let’s say you only want to run `postgres` and `redis` in development because you use managed services in production or perhaps you have `esbuild` and `tailwind` watchers running in development but not in production.
>
> That’s 2 common use cases of wanting optional `depends_on`, so now let’s say you have `web` and `worker` services defined with `depends_on` attached to them:
>
> - Before v2.19 (with the “bug”):
>
>   ```yaml
>   depends_on:
>     - "postgres"
>     - "redis"
>   ```
>
>   If you set `COMPOSE_PROFILES="web,worker"`, Docker Compose would silently allow your project to be upped without `postgres` and `redis`. This is essentially optional dependencies since it worked with or without them set to run.
> - After and including v2.19 (without the “bug”):
>
>   ```yaml
>   depends_on:
>     - "postgres"
>     - "redis"
>   ```
>
>   If you set `COMPOSE_PROFILES="web,worker"`, Docker Compose would fail to start and say you need to run `postgres` and `redis`. If you want them to always be required you can leave things how they are and you’re good to go.
> - After and including v2.20.2 (without the “bug”):
>
>   ```yaml
>     depends_on:
>       postgres:
>         condition: "service_started"
>         required: false
>       redis:
>         condition: "service_started"
>         required: false
>   ```
>
>   Now you can set required to be true or false based on your preference. You can still use the shorthand array syntax if you want them to be required by default.
>
>   Sure it’s a little more typing but I’m ok with that. I actually like seeing the condition explicitly set too because it’s clear on what criteria is used to determine the dependent service is up.